# Make dynamic marker in Flutter Google Maps e.g show name in marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Many examples on the web handle the case where one puts a custom image as marker. But how can we add a text inside the marker.

A good example of this is how Airbnb shows markers with prices in it. Like the below

[image: flutter airbnb style marker]

How can this be implemented in Flutter Google Maps

Comment: I think this could be possible with the new [Advanced Markers for Mobile SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/advanced-markers-now-available-for-ios-and-android-easily-customize-your-markers-across-platforms). Though I'm not sure if it is already available within the flutter libraries of Google Maps.